# 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Here is my `Content-Security-Policy` in `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://example.com">
```

Now i am dynamically setting img src of `<img id="updateProfilePicPreview" class="profilPicPreview" src="" />` as

```
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('updateProfilePicPreview');
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

It shows

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDACgcHiMeGSgjISMtKygw…p+tB/yaKKAIi2TSfjRRVCJFOyIk96rE5NFFDGgoooqBhRRRQA9elIDg5oopgIc+lFFFAH/2Q==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http://example.com". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

So how can i enable setting `img` src dynamically ?

I was following this example from cordova page:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: So what is your solution? Could you share more in detail thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> So how can i enable setting img src dynamically ?

The problem is not setting the src, the problem is setting the src to a data: scheme URI.

Add `data:` to the list of things allowed by the [content security policy](http://content-security-policy.com/). Either for the default-src or you could define a separate img-src.

In the example below, I have added `img-src 'self' data:;` to the start of the meta tag in the index.html file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/">
```

Comment: I am having the same problem in my Ionic App. The ng-src can be either base64 or regular URL link. All the base64 throw the same error. Could you explain more in detail how to "Add data: to the list of things allowed by the content security policy. Either for the default-src or you could define a separate img-src." ??

Comment: try `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/"> `

Comment: by adding `img-src 'self' data:;`, base64 images are visible now but images with link address throws and error now related to CSP.

Comment: Can someone please explain @Kashifali question about "myapp"?!

Comment: do I am supposed to replace `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/` with my app link `https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: @x7R5fQ Yes mate. http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/ wont work anyway because CSP does not allow specific paths/folders. I'm not even sure it can be used on IP addresses. Just put 'https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com'.