# how to display image base 64 in ionic view?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, base64

i take a picture and i convert this in base64 :

my picture in base 64:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgK......
```

and i want to display in ionic view :

my event.html

```
<img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="text-align: center">
```

but i found nothing :

[image]

my controller :

```
.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

                $scope.takePhoto = function () {
                  var options = {
                    quality: 75,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 300,
                    targetHeight: 300,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };

                    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                        console.log("$scope.imgURI");
                        console.log($scope.imgURI);
                    }, function (err) {
                        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Please share the controller code that shows how the image string is assigned to the variable you use in the view.

Comment: look please i edit it

Comment: What is `imageData`? Looks like it might be junk.  Based on Harbringer's answer below (after adding an ng-show to their example), this should work.  As they mentioned in their answer, you might want to make sure it is a valid base64 image.

Comment: it is a valid base64 , i'm sure

Comment: I think you can find in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166870/img-src-was-not-explicitly-set-so-default-src-is-used-as-a-fallback)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `takePhoto` function is getting called from somewhere:

The problem might be, that you bind to a primitive string. Please try:

```
.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

$scope.my = {imgURI: null};

                $scope.takePhoto = function () {
                  var options = {
                    quality: 75,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 300,
                    targetHeight: 300,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                  };

                    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        $scope.my.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                        console.log($scope.my.imgURI);
                    }, function (err) {
                        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    });
                }
```

By the way: please consider putting that takePhoto function in a factory or service. Than you could assign the captured image to a property of the service and directly bind to it in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a plunker that walks through what your trying to do.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XmyLCpwJTodBrMrW2QHZ

One of the things you should consider is checking out the npm validator library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator
This would allow you to verify your imageData is actually base64 example below returns true/false.

```
validator.isBase64(base64Code);
```