# base64 image not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to show base 64 images in my ionic app . I am getting images from server and i need to show these images in a slider .

```
   <ks-swiper-slide class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="(cKey,cValue) in 
     value.CHAPTER">
                        <div ng-click="chapters({{cValue.CHAPTER_ID}} , '{{cValue.CHAPTER_NAME}}')" class="hm-outbox-first"> 
                            <div  ng-class="getClass({{value.SUBJECT_ID}})" > 
                                <img data-ng-src="{{cValue.IMAGE}}"  />   
                            </div>
                            <div class="hm-bottombox">
                                <p ng-class="getSubClass({{value.SUBJECT_ID}})" > {{cValue.CHAPTER_NAME| truncatelimit:28}}  </p> 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ks-swiper-slide>
```

I have tried data-ng-src, ng-src and src to show. And they are available in the HTML as I can see them when I inspect my code. this works fine when i am using images available in my app. But from server this is not working. I tried searching for the issue didn't find any thing. Thanks in advance for the help.
Or am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: How does the data from the server look like and how do you insert it into your controller?

Comment: cValue.IMAGE must be base64 string right?
Do this instead ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{cValue.IMAGE}}"

Comment: @Rakeschand yeah this is the image , Actually i have data:image/JPEG;base64, already added to my src , and i tried it with ng-src too.

Comment: what are you getting after applying this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from one the solution here 
['img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166870/img-src-was-not-explicitly-set-so-default-src-is-used-as-a-fallback)

I need to add the line in my index.html

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/">
```

Answer (score 0):

add height and width to the image

```
<img data-ng-src="{{cValue.IMAGE}}" style="height: 200px;width:100px" />
```

and add a ng-if for outer container

```
<ks-swiper-slide ng-if="value.CHAPTER" class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="(cKey,cValue) in 
     value.CHAPTER">
</ks-swiper-slide>
```

Comment: adding height and width didn't help .

Comment: add ng-if, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{cValue.IMAGE}}"
```

Comment: i have data:image/JPEG;base64, already added to my src and i removed that and tried your solution too. But that didn't work for me :(