# Why does the preview image not show in Android when using Cordova Camera?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building an app in Ionic Framework and I'm having a problem with the preview image in Android. It just doesn't show. I use the plugin Cordova Camera to take and select pictures from your phone. On iPhone I do see the preview image, so there all is working fine.

Anyone has any idea why it's not working on Android?

This code is in controllers.js:

```
    $scope.addImage = function (type) {
        if (type == 'take') {
            $scope.cam = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        } else if (type == 'select') {
            $scope.cam = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
        }

        var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: $scope.cam,
            allowEdit: true,
            correctOrientation: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 2000,
            targetHeight: 2000,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            $scope.image = imageData;
            $scope.popover.hide();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    };
```

And the HTML in the view:

```
    <div class="edit-image" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
        <img ng-if="imgURI && imgURI === undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI }}" />
        <img ng-if="!imgURI && imgURI === undefined" src="https://example.com/noimage.jpg" />
        <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" class="take_picture" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS devices setting background-image as base64 data works as it should, but it appears that on Android devices base64 encoding data contains line-breaks at the end. Deleting them solved the problem in my case.

So in your code you need to add regular expression to get rid of line-breaks in imageData.

> $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +
>   imageData.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem you described above(in my situation it was because of my meta tag in the index.html, i had to add img-src 'self' data:;) The problem started when i upgraded from ionic v1 to v2. my meta tag before the upgrade was

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

then after the upgrade to make everything work i had to change it to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=" img-src 'self' data:; default-src *; script-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Note: The tags are for development phase

More Info follow link 
['img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166870/img-src-was-not-explicitly-set-so-default-src-is-used-as-a-fallback)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please expand your answer to include more information, as links to other answers are not best suited as answers. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more information.