# images from imgur.com is not displaying on website

Tags: html, imgur

I am using simple html tag to display images from imgur.com:

```
<img alt="Modern Dashboard Design" src="http://i.imgur.com/yst7lV9.png?1" style="height:550px; width:1024px" />
```

this was working few days back, but now it is not showing. Image is displaying on jsfiddle,but not displaying on this page:

http://www.ucom.my/p/admin-page-for-website-50

When you view the page source, you will find `img` tags.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Most likely cross domain requests are blocked. That is pretty much standard today. If that is the cause, then you need to set a header granting requests to that domain.

Comment: Refused to load the image 'http://i.imgur.com/2qEeCDA.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166870/img-src-was-not-explicitly-set-so-default-src-is-used-as-a-fallback

Comment: Google the errors that browser's tell you. You'll find SO questions just about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://i.imgur.com/2qEeCDA.png (“default-src http://www.ucom.my”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://i.imgur.com/yst7lV9.png?1 (“default-src http://www.ucom.my”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://i.imgur.com/GAXEkpu.jpg (“default-src http://www.ucom.my”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src http://www.ucom.my”).
```

This can be seen when opening the Firebug console.

You have this in your `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```

This means you have deliberately blocked all requests to imgur or anywhere else. Change it to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src example.com;">
```

Or just remove it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look in your console tells me you have a LOAD of security errors.

> Refused to load the image 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDah1.jpg' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src'
>   is used as a fallback.

And this happens because:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`

this line of code exists which disallows content from foreign sources.

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. **Read the error messages**.

> Refused to load the image 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDah1.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

You've included:

> ```
>   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
> ```

in your page, which bans the use of `<img>` elements with a `src` on a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to your browser inspector...
It says:

```
[Error] Refused to load http://i.imgur.com/2qEeCDA.png because it appears in neither the img-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
[Error] Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the style-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy. (admin-page-for-website-50, line 87)
[Error] Refused to load http://i.imgur.com/yst7lV9.png?1 because it appears in neither the img-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
[Error] Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the style-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy. (admin-page-for-website-50, line 89)
[Error] Refused to load http://i.imgur.com/GAXEkpu.jpg because it appears in neither the img-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/yst7lV9.png?1" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" alt="dashboard">
```

- Use the attribute `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"`
- Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67270094/9295698) for alternative ways to approach this issue