# Imgur images returning 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imgur

I've been making a react app and recently whenever I try to access images from imgur like so

```
this.setState({
  imgUrl: `https://i.imgur.com/${this.props.image.id}b.png`,
  imgBigUrl: `https://i.imgur.com/${this.props.image.id}l.png`
});
```

And it's being rendered like this

```
<img src={this.state.imgUrl}/>
```

But I keep getting 403 forbidden, but when I use postman or visit it in the browser it's fine. I'm also accessing the API by passing in an album url like

`https://imgur.com/gallery/zrUFj`

and getting all the images from there to be displayed in the app (where i get 403 errors)

I'm unsure where I could be have done something wrong, I've also tried getting a new client ID for the API authorization, still hasn't worked. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Imgur's CDN seems to restrict access to images from a `127.0.0.1` referer. This has been reported to them as an issue (matter of server configuration).

Meanwhile try to change your dev server host from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` or maybe your real IP address.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! If you don't mind me asking, where did you find this out? I've been searching for a while now and I haven't stumbled upon that info yet

Comment: Glad to hear that. I came across the same issue recently. Simply investigated the response headers in both cases and tried the approach. Notice that you will have the same issue with the app on production build. Just serve it on your IP address not `localhost`.

Comment: Imgur just wrote to me that they fixed the issue on their end. You may use `localhost` again.

Comment: For me the issue is the exact opposite, `127.0.0.1` doesn't work while `localhost` does

Comment: I updated the answer just now to reflect the actual case now, i.e, `127.0.0.1` doesn't work while `localhost` does.

Answer (score 15):

Note that a quick and hacky way to fix this is to simply remove the referrer header either via a `<meta>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

or in your `fetch`:

```js
await fetch("https://i.imgur.com/iie9XhM.jpg", {referrer:""})
```

or (as mentioned by @Theblockbuster1) in the `img` tag:

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iie9XhM.jpg" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, `<img src="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">` worked for me :)

Comment: This should also be the answer :)