# How can I display an image from a link in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

Let's say I have an image link: https://i.imgur.com/pPMi9ES.png

In my index.html the I have an HTML img element as following, but the image is blank after all.

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/pPMi9ES.png" width="400px" height="300px"/>
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Not sure if it's related but see [Imgur images returning 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895390/imgur-images-returning-403). Imgur might be blocking access, hence the empty image

Answer (score 1):

if you are working on local server and have address like this 127.0.0.1
try changing it to localhost. It worked for me.