# Ionic background Image not Showing?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Here Is the scss code I have use..**

```
.scroll-content{
    background-image: url("assets/imgs/bkgnd.png") !important;
}
```

***The following error is showing..***

ion-dev.js?v=3.1.8:250 Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMAAAADACAMAAABlApw1AAACWFBMVEUAAABPpf9Ck/80f/9Qpv9Bkf9Qpf81gP81f/9Qpf81gP81f/9Ppf9Qp/80f/81gP9DlP9Qpv80f/82gf81f/9Qpv81gP81f/9Rp/9Nov83g/9Ppv82gv9Nov9Qpv81f/82gP9Ppf9Ppf81gP9Rp/9Qpv9Qpv9Ppf9Qpv81f/82gf9Oov83gv9Nof9Rp/9Nof80f/9Oov83gv9PpP9Nov83g/82gP82gP////9Qpv83g/9PpP86hv9Oo/81f/84hf82gf81gP88if9JnP9Nof9Imv89i/9GmP9Knf9Dlf80fv86iP9Ckf9MoP9Lnv9Ln/9Flv9Rp/9Hmf8+jP8+jf8/jv9BkP9Aj/9Ck/9Bkf/8/v/+/v/u9v/5/P/1+v/o8v/r9P/w9v/m8f/3+//y+P/c6/8+iP9HlP/7/P/f7f/j7//a6f9Rn...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

For images only this should be enough:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self'">
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src) for more details.

Old Answer:
Is the following meta tag set in your index.html?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/">
```

This is an exiting answer to a question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32166921/3354409

Comment: can you please explain why we will use http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/, it is getting an error.

Comment: That is just the URL that is allowed, you can try *, which is not secure but is enough for dev purpose.

Comment: EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' *".

Comment: Use this pls: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self'">`