# Image in svg from external url not loaded because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"

Tags: html, image, svg, content-security-policy

So I'm trying to create an svg that contains an image from the external url `https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGwt.jpg`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="86" viewBox="0 0 300 86" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect 
    x="0"
    y="0"
    rx="5"
    ry="5"
    width="300"
    height="86"
    fill="red"
  ></rect>
  <svg x="11" y="11" width="auto">
    <image transform="translate(0,0)" width="64" height="64" ry="30" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGwt.jpg" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

The problem that if I host this svg on GitHub for example the image is not loaded and I got this error message:

> Refused to load the image 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGwt.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

You can see it live on https://github.com/johannchopin/poc-svg/blob/main/svg.svg.

I read on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32166921/8583669) that I have to add some meta tag like:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/">
```

However when I add it at the top of my svg nothing change. Has anyone an idea how I could see my avatar in the svg on GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...>` works only if placed in the `<head>` section.

And unfortunately Github publishes its own CSP via HTTP header:
[image]

This header disallows images therefore blocks SVG. There is no way to relax this CSP if you are not Github admin, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I guess the only think that I can do to bypass that is to add the image as a base64 string :/